# Порождённый процесс и компиляция .cpp фала

Tags: c++, c++-cli

Поставили задачу написать программу, которая бы компилировала, собирала и запускала .cpp файл, но я пока могу только запустить уже собранный .exe и то функция была как пример. Не смог найти в интернете, как это сделать, думаю, здесь меня поймут и помогут с решением этой задачи

```
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        printf("SPAWN_v:\n");
        status(spawnv(P_WAIT, pathname, args)); //pathname - путь к файлу
    }
```

P.S. Компилировать собираюсь просто обычный C++

Comment: Компилировать собираетесь нормальный C++ или C++/CLI? ЗЫ: это два **разных** языка.

Comment: Собираюсь компилировать обычный c++

Comment: "но я пока могу только запустить уже собранный .exe" компилятор это тоже .exe Бери какой-нибудь portable version of MinGW и запускай.